# How To Reload data from URL ???Only Can Load data in viewdidload?

Tags: iphone, url, sdk, cell, reloaddata

OK，First this program can load plist from URL by this code，and I put this in

```
- (void)viewdidLoad{
   NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://someurl.php"]
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
            timeoutInterval:60.0];

 NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
 NSLog(@"\n\nCONNECTION:   %@", theConnection);
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
 NSString *listFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];   
 self.plist = [listFile propertyList];
}
```

than I take the plist file to init the tableview cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

 LightCell0 *cell =(LightCell0 *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[LightCell0 alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
 }
 // Set up the cell…
 [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];

  cell.lightLocation.text =  [[[self.plist objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"nodeName"]description];


       return cell;

}
```

now I need to keep reloading the URL data to init it

So I add

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:REFRESH_STATUS_TIME
                target:self
                 selector:@selector(timerFired:)
                 userInfo:nil
               repeats:YES];

}
```

and change the get URLrequest from `(void)viewDidLoad` to

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.php"]
             cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
            timeoutInterval:60.0];

 NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
 NSLog(@"\n\nCONNECTION:   %@", theConnection);
 NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
 NSString *listFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];   
 self.plist = [listFile propertyList];
 NSLog(@"Timefired!!!!");
}
```

**HERE IS THE PROBLEM ~**

The TableView cell init seems didn't get any plist data from the `timeFired`

I check the console result,I can see there is a plist data get back every 3 sec
(define REFRESH_STATUS_TIME = 3.0;)

**What's Wrong When My program Reload Data pass to cell failed??**

Comment: OH I SET A Breakpoint at - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {...} DID NOT STOP AT HERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't see any lines with `[self.tableView reloadData];`. You have to call this to reload your table view data

Comment: Does it call your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {...} ?

Comment: NO... I think it not call this function,because it's no stop at next line under the break point

Comment: also this one is not call "- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.plist count];
}"

Comment: If youor country is very late ,we can try figure out this question tomorrow ....sorry about that

Comment: are you sure that it calls your `[self.tableView reloadData];`